# rails-3 cron job not working with rails runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, cron-task, runner

Recently I came across the following tutorial of running cron job without using any Gems
http://www.ameravant.com/posts/recurring-tasks-in-ruby-on-rails-using-runner-and-cron-jobs

I create one file in /app/delete_old_posts.rb

```
  class DeleteOldPosts < ActiveRecord::Base          
    # This script deletes all posts that are over 5 minutes old          
     post_ids = Post.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at < ?", 5.minutes.ago])          
     if post_ids.size > 0     
      Post.destroy(post_ids)     
      puts "#{post_ids.size} posts have been deleted!"       
     end
```

Then create cron job by giving crontab -e command and in console of cronjob I wrote

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/env ruby /home/abc/xyz/urjit.rajgor/workspace/thewall/rails/runner/home/XYZ/ABC/urjit.rajgor/workspace/thewall/app/delete_old_posts.rb
```

cron job run after every two minutes but it did not work
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: If that's the actual crontab command, it looks like you're missing a `/` before `home`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
But sorry I edited the command there is already / before home but it still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "whenever" gem.
Allows you to define your cronjobs in ruby being able to specify rails runner, rake, or other custom wrappers and it handles writing the crontab for you.  Makes life much simpler.

Just add: `gem 'whenever', :require => false`to your gemfile

https://github.com/javan/whenever

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I try to install it and it gave me this error when I ran wheneverize . command 
Error is wheneverize: command not found
so, can you help me doing this without using any Gem?

Comment: Did you execute it with bundle exec?

Comment: If you are curious as to why it works now, check out the sytax they use with rails runner.

Comment: hey can you answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256331/whenever-delayed-job-with-cron-job-in-starting-worker